# Hover not working in hyperlinks using tailwind css

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I tried to change the color of the list created below while hovering but it doesnot do what it is supposed to do . I can't figure out what i am missing here.

```
<ul className="ul">
  <li>
    <a className="hover:text-white bg-purple border-white rounded-sm" href="#">abcd</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works, but when You use `hover:` in **`tailwindcss`** You need to be more [specific and exactly](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states). Below example with your code snippet(*I changed a little to see the effect*). You might simple convert this code to `react.js` adding `className` instead of `class`.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="h-full">
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="hover:text-white hover:bg-purple-600 hover:border-gray-300 border-2 rounded-sm p-3" href="#">It Works!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So, I should give hover prefix to every property I need to have hover effect.

Comment: @sumitkhatrii exactly ;-) Good Luck and best regards!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is already solved, but it seems that searches for similar problems are redirected here, so I'll give a second solution in case this isn't the case in particular.

If you are using Tailwind **regardless of the environment where you use** it as an example with some **framework** or if it is through **CDN**, you must be specific with the path of your files in `tailwind.config` in the content object

example:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I just run the "npm run build" command to build css-file and it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34346032)